# Does Thunderbolt speed provide a benefit over USB 3.0 for an external hard disk?

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-3, thunderbolt

Numbers imply that Thunderbolt is faster than USB 3.0. But, is there any external hard drive that can **really** reach this speed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this ssd benchmark](http://ssd.userbenchmark.com/) the fastest SSD (2016) has a write performance of 512MB/s (read performance is a little bit higher, but not significantly)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB) shows 5GB/s as maximum throughput of an USB 3.0 port.

As you can see, this is a multiple of the maximum of what a current hard disk can support.

To answer your question: There is no external hard disk (at the moment) that would use the higher speed of thunderbolt.

An [article](http://www.itpro.co.uk/storage/22740/usb-vs-thunderbolt-which-is-better) from 2 years ago did explicit tests and found out: no difference in speed for thunderbolt vs. USB 3 regarding hard discs.

Comment: The only reason I would pay for the premium of a Thunderbolt device, is if I had several, allowing more devices to reach their maximum transfer rate compared to USB 3..

Comment: PCIe based SSD read with other 2 Gigabyte/s

Answer (score 1):

Yes, PCIe based SSD like the [Samsung 950 Pro](http://www.samsung.com/us/computing/memory-storage/solid-state-drives/ssd-950-pro-nvme-512gb-mz-v5p512bw/) or the [Intel SSD 750](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/solid-state-drives/solid-state-drives-750-series.html) can have read speeds larger 2 GB/s (Gigabyte, not Gigabit).

Here using the SSD in in [enclosure connected via Thunderbold 3](https://www.akitio.com/expansion/thunder3-pcie-ssd)

[image]

gives you a dramatic perf improvement over using a SATA SSD in an USB 3.0 enclosure.

[image]