# Fastest external hard drive interface nowadays

Tags: external-hard-drive, usb-storage, usb-3, esata, thunderbolt

I run virtual machines from an external hard drive from my Mac (internal SSD is not big enough for what I do).

My question is:

Which would the fastest external interface be nowadays assuming I have the fastest SSD hard drive on it?

- USB-3
- USB Type C
- Thunderbolt
- eSata
- Other?

What would you guys recommend?

Thanks!

Comment: [use Thunderbolt 3](https://superuser.com/a/1116387/174557) with PCIe/M2 enclosure, this is the fastest way.

Answer (score 1):

Go for USB type-C. It has at least 5Gbps bandwidth and might be compatible with some mobile devices' OTG feature. Also, newly released ultra-thin laptops tend to include only USB type-C.